# [WSO2 APIM 4.1][WSO2 IS 5.11] Changing the Owner of an Application / http error 401

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I have configured a distributed wso2 api management platform with separated traffic manager and an identity server as key manager:

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/deploying-wso2-api-m-in-a-distributed-setup-with-tm-separated/

I am trying to change the ownership of an application as desribed the instructions in the documentation below :

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/consume/manage-application/advanced-topics/changing-the-owner-of-an-application/

It works fine but as soon as i generate client credentials for my application, i no longer can change the owner and I get the following error .

```
TID: [-1234] [api/am/admin] [2022-08-17 18:09:07,903] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.admin.v1.impl.ApplicationsApiServiceImpl} - Error while updating application owner 9eaefedz7b-e4e6fefeefeeea-f8410fefefre53 org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error occurred while updating OAuth Client :
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractKeyManager.handleException_aroundBody12(AbstractKeyManager.java:274)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractKeyManager.handleException(AbstractKeyManager.java:272)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.updateApplicationOwner_aroundBody6(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:402)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.updateApplicationOwner(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:390)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.updateApplicationOwner_aroundBody178(APIConsumerImpl.java:4707)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.updateApplicationOwner(APIConsumerImpl.java:4667)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.admin.v1.impl.ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.applicationsApplicationIdChangeOwnerPost(ApplicationsApiServiceImpl.java:67)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.admin.v1.ApplicationsApi.applicationsApplicationIdChangeOwnerPost(ApplicationsApi.java:56)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:265)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:304)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:217)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:107)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:110)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:102)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:101)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:146)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:58)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:126)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.kmclient.KeyManagerClientException: Received status code: 401 Reason:
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.kmclient.KMClientErrorDecoder.decode_aroundBody0(KMClientErrorDecoder.java:42)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.kmclient.KMClientErrorDecoder.decode(KMClientErrorDecoder.java:35)
        at feign.AsyncResponseHandler.handleResponse(AsyncResponseHandler.java:96)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:138)
        at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:89)
        at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:100)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy440.updateApplicationOwner(Unknown Source)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.updateApplicationOwner_aroundBody6(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:398)
        ... 57 more
```

I don't understand why the identity server sends 401 http status ! Can anybody help =) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got http 401 cuz the resource called while trying to update the ownership of an application (with authorization keys) was not allowed due the resources acces control configuration in identity server dployment.toml file :

```
context = "(.)/keymanager-operations/dcr/register(.)"
secure = true
http_method = "POST"
permissions = "/permission/admin/manage/identity/applicationmgt/update"
scopes = "internal_application_mgt_update"
```

it works after changing the context parameter in the configuration above, from :

```
context = "(.)/keymanager-operations/dcr/register(.)"
```

to :

```
context = "(.*)/keymanager-operations/dcr/register(.*)"
```